# i replaced cv axle but still making squealing noises

Tags: axle

i have a 2005 hyundai sonata. Can a cv axle made for anti lock brakes be used on my car if i dont anti lock brakes? friend installed anyway.

Comment: I just did a part search and see no evidence there are different parts for antilock brakes. Kind of surprised they weren't standard. (where in the world are you?).  Note there are different parts depending on which engine you have, and it is entirely possible they are nearly the same but slightly different length.

Answer (score 0):

Does the cv axle really have anything to do with ABS? The cv axle is just splined from the trans to the hub, so I’d say yes you can use the cv axle!

Comment: thank you   , wasnt sure if i had to get the one that says without anti-lock brakes

Comment: There may or may not be a tone wheel on the hub side of the axle. That's what's meant by ABS/Non-ABS. Some setups are different where the tone wheel is part of the wheel bearing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Both versions of the axle are the same length. The only difference is the tone wheel that's pressed on to the knuckle end of the axle. See Napa part numbers [NMD 958395](https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NMD958395) & [NMD 958399](https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NMD958399).